# Use new ChannelFactory<TChannel>(string) if the config is in a string?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-config

I would like to use the [ChannelFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms574913%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) to create a WCF Client for a given endpoint.

The problem is that I don't have a web.config or app.config, but I do have the whole `<system.serviceModel>` XML block in a string.

I do not want to manually parse that out and programatically create the BIndings and Endpoints when I already have the configuration.

Is there a way to tell the ChannelFactory to just use that block as it's configuration? Or at least create a [ServiceEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.serviceendpoint%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better solution: [`ConfigurationChannelFactory<TChannel>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd575311.aspx) allows creating a WCF Channel from a custom configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There's a technique described in [this blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2007/10/19/loading-the-wcf-configuration-from-different-files-on-the-client-side.aspx).

It isn't as simple as one line of code, but at least it's working at a level higher than raw XML.

Comment: That worked. Not as simple as I'd like it to be, but it works and saves me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually create binding and endpoint address to create an instance of the CHannelFactory, something like:

```
   BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding() { 
       Name = "Bindingname"
       // Goes all the necessary members to set.
   };

   EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://serviceendpoint.com");
   ChannelFactory<IContract> factory = new ChannelFactory<IContract>(binding, endpoint);
```

Then you can try using factory.CreateChannel() to explore the members of it before your ServiceEnpoint, Behaviors, etc.

Hope this help, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote: `I do not want to manually parse that out and programatically create the Bindings and Endpoints when I already have the configuration.`. I'm using the programmatic way already, but I want to stop duplicating code as I have a `<system.serviceModel>` XML Block already.

Comment: My bad, I thought you might convert it to generics to lessen the code in creating instance of `ChannelFactory<TChannel>` for every contract.